# How to find which module created a particular menu item in Drupal via hook_menu

Tags: drupal-7

If i know the path of the menu item is there a quick way to find what module that defines the particular menu item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu_link array has a key called 'module' that you can use to know which module added a link.

If the path you're searching for has no dynamic parts, then something like `db_query('SELECT mlid FROM {menu_links} WHERE link_path = :link_path',array(':link_path' => 'some/drupal/path'))->fetchField();` will help you find the mlid that you can use with `menu_link_load()` to get the full menu item array and check for the 'module' key.

Unfortunately, the 'module' value is set to 'system' when modules add new path through `hook_menu()`, so you won't be able to know which module really added a that by doing just this.

The only other solution that comes to my mind is to use module_implements() to discover which modules are using hook_menu() to add paths to the menu, and then manually invoking their implementation of hook_menu() and iterating the returned values to see if you can find the path, much like [menu_router_build()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_router_build/7) does. This does not take into account the fact that some other module may alter the menu, though, unless you also manually invoke hook_menu_alter().

In case the path you're searching has dynamic parts (e.g. node/**3**, or user/**1**), then you can use [menu_get_item()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7) to get the path string, as exposed in the hook_menu() of the module that defined that path, and use it with the second solution, to get the related module.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the easiest way that comes to my mind is to search for the path in the source code. Don't forget to replace the path segments that you know to be dynamic by %.